# UX Research methods, advantages and disadvantages

Tags: user-research

Can someone comprehensively enlist all the UX research methods, their advantages and disadvantages and in what scenarios they should be used ?
Thank you.

Comment: What you're asking for will fill several textbooks, which is too broad to be answerable here on UX.SE. Here's a very very brief overview: http://www.measuringu.com/blog/method-when.php

Comment: no, sorry I can't.

Answer (score 2):

The methods used in UX research are many and are mostly borrowed from other disciplines such as anthropology and sociology. There are many textbooks and courses that explain different methods in details. User researchers often triangulate different methods to answer the research questions or overcome some of the constraints they are facing.

**Universal Methods of Design** is a book that I found useful as a quick reference. It is quite accessible and present high level overview of different methods with supporting images. It also talks where in the design process they are most useful, but to learn more about the methods explained other resources can be helpful. Here is the link to the book: http://amzn.com/1592537561

Comment: Might want to also consider reading Universal Principles of Design before you check out the actual methods. Link to the book: http://www.amazon.com/Universal-Principles-Design-William-Lidwell/dp/1592530079